# Change font-color of placeholder span on input focus

Tags: jquery, html

I have an input field with a span placeholder inside of it. What I'd like to do is change the color of the placeholder when the input field is clicked. Here is a jsFiddle with an example of my field.

http://jsfiddle.net/Vbnj2/

What's the best way to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a selector for the input element and then grab the previous span. Add a class that affects the color. On blur remove the class.

http://jsfiddle.net/Vbnj2/1/

```
$("span.holder + input").focus( function() {
    $(this).prev('span.holder').addClass('active');
}).blur(function() {
    $(this).prev('span.holder').removeClass('active');
});
```

Modern browsers have added support for the `placeholder` attribute. You just add `placeholder="My Text"` as an input attribute and the browser will automatically insert/remove it as necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is different to the way you've approached it, but if what you're trying to do is remove the holder text on focus, you could always use [this here](http://jsfiddle.net/HelloJoe/9AqtQ/)

What it does is read the text from your inputs `title` attribute, you set the color of the default text in your css and then when you focus/blur it adds/removes text, unless there is a value, then the users value stays there rather then the default text.

HTML

```
<input type="text" name="firstname" class="defaultText" title="First Name" />
```

CSS

```
input { margin: 10px; padding: 5px; }

.defaultTextActive { color: #000; }
```

jQuery

```
$(".defaultText").focus(function(srcc) {

    if ($(this).val() == $(this)[0].title) {
        $(this).removeClass("defaultTextActive");
        $(this).val("");
    }

});

$(".defaultText").blur(function() {

    if ($(this).val() == "") {
        $(this).addClass("defaultTextActive");
        $(this).val($(this)[0].title);
    }

});

$(".defaultText").blur();
```