# How do you change a placeholder's attributes and styles?

Tags: javascript, attributes, styles, placeholder

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change an input’s HTML5 placeholder color with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610497/change-an-inputs-html5-placeholder-color-with-css)
>   [Change font-color of placeholder span on input focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8046040/change-font-color-of-placeholder-span-on-input-focus)

**Placeholder Attributes and Styles**

How do you change a placeholder's styles?

For example:(font-family,size,color,etc.)

Comment: Apparently not as trivial as I thought: http://blog.ajcw.com/2011/02/styling-the-html5-placeholder/

Answer (score 0):

jQuery  `$('.class').css('color', '#334455');` same for the other CSS properties

Comment: This doesn't change the place holder color.

Comment: what actually is the 'placeholder'? actually the best way os to add/remove a class - but I'm answer what is asked.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with css. Have a look at the answer here. [Change an HTML5 input's placeholder color with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610497/change-an-inputs-html5-placeholder-color-with-css)

More or less use

```
input:-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color:    #999;
}
input:-moz-placeholder {
    color:    #999;
}
input:-ms-input-placeholder {
    color:    #999;
}
```